# run Report SSRS into SSIS and send it by email

Tags: ssis

I'm loking for a solution to create a project to run a report created in SSRS and send it by email to users..
I'm no familiar with C# to write my script task..

Finally I want to schedule a job in SQL server that run this project everyday

some idea or samples for me!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if ssrs is configured correctly, you just need to set up a subscription to the report to have it emailed on a schedule.

Comment: That's right, no need to use SSIS here. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159762.aspx

Comment: how can I setup the subscription?

Comment: See the link in @santiiiii's comment above.  The short answer is run the report from the reporting services website, choose the option to create a subscription from the report options on the toolbar, and follow the prompts.  You can do this from 2005 or 2008 in any edition other than Sql Express.